# Fatal Error: comdef.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, excel, eclipse, compilation, aspose

I installed Aspose.Cells and tried to write a simple C++ file that includes `Aspose.Cells.h`. I soon realized that I had to install two other external libraries, boost and  icu4c as without these libraries my compiler would throw errors saying some h or hpp files can not be found.

My problem is:  even after I installed these libraries, I still couldn’t compile my code, as I received a new error saying “Fatal ERROR: comdef.h: No such file or directory.”

And the error persisted even after I installed the latest version for SDK for Win 10.

My simple file can run if I remove  the line "#include Aspose.Cells.h" .

Can someone please enlighten me as to how to solve this error?

Also I noticed there is a folder called “Publish” under “include” folder for Aspose.Cells. This folder is besides boost and icu. Could this mean Publish is the third external library to be installed? But I couldn’t find any library called Public on the web. Pls see the screenshot below.
[directory of include folder that comes with the installed Aspose.Cells package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuRYZ.png)
Thanks a lot!

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Aspose.Cells.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "hello!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Regards
Hillary

Comment: Even although your Windows might be 64 bit, it still is able to run 32 bit code as well. So, you also can build 32 bit as well as 64 bit DLLs and executables. (There is usually an option to chose the platform to build for.) Of course, you may not mix 32 and 64 bit DLLs for one executable.

Comment: I just had a look into the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10` of my box. In sub-folder `bin`, you find a lot of stuff separated in `x86` and `x64` sub-sub-folders. So, your Windows Kits is prepared for 32 bit as well as 64 bit. (Nothing to worry about.)

Comment: I just got reply from Aspose support and the answer is clear now: Aspose only support Visual Studio.....

Comment: I'm not an expert concerning Eclipse (just that I heard about it). From other IDEs, I know that the used compiler is subject of configuration. So, there might be a chance to configure Eclipse for use of MSVC++. On the other hand, I use VS daily, and it's one of the best IDEs I have seen so far. There is a [community version which can be used for free](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/vs/community/). ;-)

Comment: thank you scheff I have decided to switch to VS for C++, but I noticed they don't provide technical support  for free , which is sad.... as i have installation issue with VS 2019.

Comment: There is a forum at the Microsoft site (where I'm not member but found answers from time to time). SO might be good for a question as well. Use of VS2019 is not that exotic.

Comment: thanks I will give it a try

Comment: Actually, you don't have to install any libraries. You can simply open "Demo.sln" demo project (from the release archive in Demo folder) with Visual Studio 2017 or higher which is already configured environment, so you may add your code to it easily.  PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.